# Take out certain elements in a Json String

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this Json snippet (simplified)

```
[
  {
    "ReferenceId": 0,
    "MasterId": 1,    
    "BuildType": {
      "DisplayName": null,      
    },
    "Type": {
      "DisplayName": null,      
    },    
    "IsActive": true,
    "Name": "Product1",
    "Id":1
  },
  {
    "ReferenceId": 0,
    "MasterId": 1,    
    "BuildType": {
      "DisplayName": null,      
    },
    "Type": {
      "DisplayName": null,      
    },    
    "IsActive": false,
    "Name": "Product2",
    "Id":2
  }
]
```

I want to intercept this string removed all the IsActive: false and return a string that represents a valid Json Array

So far I have

```
JArray jArrayResponse = JArray.Parse(response);
//json = jArrayResponse.Where(x => x["IsActive"].ToString() == "true").ToString();
```

The .ToString() just gives me "System.Ienumberable", and I am not even sure the Where clause is working yet.

Comment: You could use NewtonSoft, convert it to an object that does not have the 'IsActive' property, then use NewtonSoft to re-serialize to JSON.

Comment: You may also be able to do a string replace, replacing "/"IsActive/": false," with nothing - but not knowing your entire Json structure I can't say if it would cause issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off.  The trick is to pass the `IEnumerable<JToken>` from the `Where` clause into a new `JArray` then convert *that* to string.  Also, you can cast the `IsActive` JValues directly to `bool`:

```
JArray jArrayResponse = JArray.Parse(response);
var json = new JArray(jArrayResponse.Where(x => (bool)x["IsActive"])).ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lt9iWS

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you create the similar types in your application based on your JSON.

```
public class BuildType
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public BuildType BuildType { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize to those type

```
List<RootObject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Perform the filter like

```
var data = ro.Where(r => r.IsActive);
```